# are Steps in gatling cached and only executed once?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have a simulation with a step that allows me to publish to different endpoints.

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  
  // some init code 

  var testTitle = this.getClass.getSimpleName
  
  val myscenario = scenario("Scn Description")
    .exec(PublishMessageRandom(pConfigTest, testTitle + "-" + numProducers, numProducers))   
  
  if (testMode == "debug") {
    setUp(
      myscenario.inject(
        atOnceUsers(1)
      )
    ).protocols(httpConf)    
  } else if (testMode == "open") {
    setUp(
      myscenario.inject(       
        rampConcurrentUsers(concurrentUserMin) to (concurrentUserMax) during (durationInMinutes minutes),
      )
    ).protocols(httpConf)
  }
}
```

Now here is my `PublishMessageRandom` definition

```
def PublishMessageRandom(producerConfig : ProducerConfig, testTitle : String, numberOfProducers : Int ) = { 
      
      val jsonBody = producerConfig.asJson
      val valuedJsonBody = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true).print(jsonBody)
      println(valuedJsonBody)
        
      val nodes : Array[String]  = endpoints.split(endpointDelimiter)
      val rnd = scala.util.Random
      val rndIndex = rnd.nextInt(numberOfProducers)      
      var endpoint = "http://" + nodes(rndIndex) + perfEndpoint      
      println("endpoint:" + endpoint)

      exec(http(testTitle)    
      .post(endpoint)    
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
      .body(StringBody(valuedJsonBody))
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("serverResponse"))
    )
    // the below is only useful in debug mode. Comment it out for longer tests
    /*.exec { session =>
      println("server_response: " + session("serverResponse").as[String])
      println("endpoint:" + endpoint)
      session */
    }
  }
```

as you can see it simply round-robin of endpoints. Unfortunately I see the above  `println("endpoint:" + endpoint)` once and it looks like it picks one endpoint randomly and keeps hitting that instead of desired purpose of hitting endpoints randomly.

Can someone explain that behavior? Is Gatling caching the Step or and how do I go around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use feeder to solve the problem where the feeder takes the random endpoint.

```
  // feeder is random endpoint as per number of producers
  val endpointFeeder = GetEndpoints(numProducers).random
  
  val myscenario = scenario("Vary number of producers hitting Kafka cluster")
    .feed(endpointFeeder)
    .exec(PublishMessageRandom(pConfigTest, testTitle + "-" + numProducers))
```

and Publish message random looks like this:

```
def PublishMessageRandom(producerConfig : ProducerConfig, testTitle : String ) = { 
      
      val jsonBody = producerConfig.asJson
      val valuedJsonBody = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true).print(jsonBody)
      println(valuedJsonBody)        
     
      exec(http(testTitle)    
      .post("${endpoint}")
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
      .body(StringBody(valuedJsonBody))
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("serverResponse"))
    )

  }
```

you see the line above  `.post("${endpoint}")` will end up hitting the endpoint coming from the feeder.

The feeder function GetEndpoints is defined as follows
where we create an array of maps with one value each "endpoint" is the key.

```
 def GetEndpoints(numberOfProducers : Int ) : Array[Map[String,String]] = {  
      val nodes : Array[String]  = endpoints.split(endpointDelimiter)        
      var result : Array[Map[String,String]] = Array()
      for( elt <- 1 to numberOfProducers ) {   
        var endpoint = "http://" + nodes(elt-1) + perfEndpoint      
        var m : Map[String, String] = Map()
        m += ("endpoint" -> endpoint )
        result = result :+ m  
        println("map:" + m)    
      }
      result
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the official [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#exec):

> Warning
>
> Gatling DSL components are immutable ActionBuilder(s) that have to be
> chained altogether and are only built once on startup. The results is
> a workflow chain of Action(s). These builders don’t do anything by
> themselves, they don’t trigger any side effect, they are just
> definitions. As a result, creating such DSL components at runtime in
> functions is completely meaningless.

Comment: Thanks I must have missed that documentation. May I ask how can I achieve my objective here?

Comment: You should read the full documentation. You have to push user specific data into its Session and then use Gatling Expression Language to resolve parameters dynamically based on the Session's content.

Comment: so looks like I need a feeder to feed the random endpoint? I am still trying to wrap my head around Gatling DSL it's not intuitive